# Equivalence classes form induced relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I am completely stuck on a question that is as follows

```
Let B = {0,1,2,3,4} and let {0},{1,3,4},{2} be a partition of B             
that induces a relation Q.
Find the distinct equivalence classes of Q
```

I do not even know where to start with this question and any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If P is a partition of a set S, then the relation R defined by xRy iff there exists A in P with x,y in A is, an equivalence relation for which P is the equivalent classes.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate further, I believe that i am a little closer to understanding but im not able to pull it all together